# Nokogiri separation tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

**I have to tag a separation by `-`**

**Example:**

```
require 'nokogiri'
teste = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse("")

Nokogiri::XML::Builder.with(teste) do |x|
  x.root('xmlns:ns3' => 'Example namespace') do
    x['ns3'].example "Example Test"
  end
end
puts teste.to_xml
```

**Output**

```
<exemplo>teste xml</exemplo>
```

**Required output**

```
<ns3:exemplo-teste>teste</ns3:exemplo-teste>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Nokogiri::XML::Builder.with(teste) do |x|
  x.root('xmlns:ns3' => 'Example namespace') do
    x['ns3'].send('example-test', 'Example Test')
  end
end
```

Output will be:

```
</root><root xmlns:ns3="Example namespace">
  <ns3:example-test>Example Test</ns3:example-test>
</root>
```